# KineticJS version 5.1 paint with mouse setPoints Push

Tags: kineticjs

Updating my application form Kinetic 4.3 to 5.1, I used the following to paint line with points array.

```
layer.on("mousemove", function () {
            if (!drawing) {
                return;
            };
            points.push(stage.getMousePosition());
            line.setPoints(points);
            layer.drawScene();
        });
```

Please see it here http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/9xear3j7/

I changed:

```
getMousePosition() to getPointerPosition()
```

It does not work!  Is the problem in this line:

```
 line.setPoints(points);
```

Please see it at http://jsfiddle.net/user373721/rmvj2vfr/
Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different points API. `[x1, y1, x2, y2, ...]`

http://jsfiddle.net/rmvj2vfr/1/

Comment: Thank you, this is the second time you helped me with KineticJS very much appreciated, it works great.